# asp.net ObjectDataSource return object from cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

Is there any way to return object from Session when Select is called on ObjectDataSource? Specifically, I have Products object and saved in **Session**. Now on another page I have ObjectDataSource which will call same bussiness object method to get Products object. Here I want to hook up any event like Selecting and I would like to return Products object from Session to Select method of ObjectDataSource.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the method as static and access the Session inside the method using HttpContext.Current.Session["products"].

Answer (score 0):

ObjectDataSource has property EnableCaching property which can be set to true.[Enable Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.enablecaching.aspx)